# How to change the timezone of the tablet with the "automatic" time setting enabled?

Tags: android, timezone

I have an issue with the tablet I use. A lot of these tablets will be used in this project. I am making the platform part of the project (which contains functionality that other project depend on) and am responsible for the system. Now, we have bought a lot of tablets and i have a problem with the timezone.

It is very important that the tablet updates it's time regularly, so I'd think it is important to use the "automatic" time value in the Android settings. The problem is, that the tablet displays a time that is one hour early. The different projects depend on the system time, so it is not possible to change the code for this bug (some projects are developed by other companies).

Is there a possibility to change the timezone in Android while using the automatic time values?

The tablet runs Android 2.2 and has root access. I am able to fix this problem in Java or even in a Linux deamon. Unfortunately, I do not own the Android source code of the tablet because these aren't published.

Comment: Root? Just add "ClockSync" for free from Android Market. Job done :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you should probably make sure the devices update at the moment.  So you're going to need a time which is the same for all timezones.

Look at :
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); 
cal.set(year + 1900,     month, day, hour, minute, second); 
cal.getTime().getTime();
```

Just use a general timezone for the devices.